# RegEx to match sub-string of a URL

Tags: regex, url

I am in the need of a Regex to match single post permalink but not pagination page, category or certain exception pages (RSS feed page, contact page, etc):

```
valid => http://anysitexxxx.com/a-single-post/
invalid => http://anysitexxxx.com/
invalid => http://anysitexxxx.com/category/running
invalid => http://anysitexxxx.com/category/running/1
invalid => http://anysitexxxx.com/page/2
invalid => http://anysitexxxx.com/page/3
invalid => http://anysitexxxx.com/feed -> sample of certain execption
```

This is intended  for Google Analytics  URL goal matching purposes- can someone with this experience help me? Thanks

Comment: That's nice, and where is the probem?

Comment: This is the problem. :) Need a Regular expression that can processes URLS such as above, to ONLY match the URLs at the top(with "valid" prefixed to it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use negative lookahead with the exceptions you don't want

```
http:\/\/anysitexxxx\.com\/(?!category|page|feed).+
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/xB4qD1/1)

Comment: How interesting! I haven't done any hardcore RegEx(C++) for years. So interesting this whole area of string processing is!

Comment: THANK YOU. WIll confirm it works and be back later. (Demo works fine). THank you.

Comment: Hi, how do I make sure it ONLY matches the following and no other forms of URLs?

Comment: What do you mean by making sur it ONLY matches the following and no other forms of URLs? Could you provide me an example?

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for all your responses. PLease ignore this question(and post). I was actually trying to help someone I never knew before, (un)fortunately that connection has now ended. So, please ignore this question and thank you again for your wisdom.  I have marked the answer as correct as it's technically correct and highly useful for similar scenarios that someone else may encounter.